# emacs org-mode: how to choose font when exporting to HTML?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

A file under `org-mode` can be exported to HTML using this:

```
C-c C-e h o
```

or

```
(org-export-dispatch) h o
```

And you'll get that ugly looking times font...

Is there a **simple** way to set another font?

Also interested in what is the *proper* (complicated) way :)

Comment: Yes, you can use arbitrary CSS to style. If I find the time and nobody beats me to it, I might make this a proper answer, but you can find some info in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/org.html#CSS-support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different options, depending on how elaborate you want to get...
Easiest:

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style>*{font-family: serif !important}</style>
```

More advanced:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyleSheet.css"/>
```

You can also put it all into a setup file and include it in your org-file:

```
#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-0.org
```

In that file there could be stuff like this (in this case, Charset, your stylesheet, Mathjax for nice Latex-style formulars):

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <meta charset="utf-8">
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/myStyle.css" />
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <script async type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mathjax/MathJax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's precisely what I was after: `#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style>*{font-family: serif !important}</style>` - a simple one liner to change all the font.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, always manually adding options is really a pain in the a**.

Here is an automatic way to do it (add to .emacs.d/init.el):

```
(defun my-change-style (backend)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (insert "#+OPTIONS: html-postamble:nil")
    (newline)
    (insert "#+OPTIONS: org-html-head-include-default-style:nil")
    (newline)
    (insert "#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style>*{font-family: sans-serif !important; font-size: small;}</s\
tyle>")
    (newline)
    ))
(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook #'my-change-style)
```

This injects the text right prior to the export in the top lines. In this example, we disable some cruft like validation link, author and date, and adjust the font.