# emacs org export HTML: custom paragraph vs list margins

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415911/emacs-org-mode-how-to-choose-font-when-exporting-to-html/51438947#51438947) simple solution, I've used `margin-left` and `margin-right` to get the exported HTML page in a more reading friendly format with larger margins both sides:

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style>*{margin-left: 2em}*{margin-right: 2em}</style>
```

So the page looks like:

```
        This is a very long sentence as an 
        example of reading friendly large
        margins in the exported HTML document
        of my org file.
```

Instead of:

```
This is a very long sentence as an example of not-reading friendly small margins
in the exported HTML document of my org file.
```

The paragraphs do look better. However, the problem now is that the increased margins affect the TOC and all the list items in the body. Somethings like:

```
- List item 1
          - Subitem 1.1
          - Subitem 1.2
                   - Subsubitem 1.2.1
- List Item 2
          - Subitem 2.1
          - Subitem 2.2
```

where I'd much rather see:

```
- List item 1
  - Subitem 1.1
  - Subitem 1.2
    - Subsubitem 1.2.1
- List Item 2
  - Subitem 2.1
  - Subitem 2.2
```

Now, is it possible to set a custom margin for text paragraphs only, not affecting lists? What would be a neat way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below css

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:<style> *{margin-left: 2em;margin-right: 2em}    ul, ol, li, a {margin: 0;} </style>
```

OR

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:<style> p{margin-left: 2em;margin-right: 2em} </style>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. For the sake of completeness (and for the ones not familiar with HTML), if you show in your answer the full emacs format `#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA` line, I'll accept it and vote it up.

Comment: Unfortunately, it all has to fit on one line: org-mode does not parse the CSS, it just stuffs it as is into the HTML output. I fixed that. You can use  a CSS file also: when the CSS becomes too long and complicated, it's better to isolate it into its own file.

Comment: You could use multiple lines by repeating the `#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:` at the start of each line. But in that case better use a CSS file as you've mentioned. In my simple case, one long line fixed my preferred font, paragraph style and lists, that's all I wanted to make the export look better.